# Unable to setup Ethereum Mining Software

Tags: wallets

I have followed the below steps:

1. downloaded `geth`, copied to C: drive.
2. executed `geth acount new` in command prompt.
3. downloaded the mist wallet and tried to install it, but it got stuck at:

   > Ethereum node needs to sync, please wait... Looking for peers...

   since the last 24 hours.

I do not know what to do. Can you please help me setting it up?

Comment: did it connect to any peer?

Comment: no it is not connecting to any peer

Comment: This is usually caused by issues with your router's NAT configuration. Are you on an enterprise network? You can try manually adding peers using https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Connecting-to-the-network#static-nodes